# How much minimum driver memory should be in spark application?

Tags: apache-spark

In spark doc it shows default memory is 1GB can we set it to less than 1 GB.I am providing 634 mb but it is giving error Application is running beyond physical limit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can set it below 1 GB .I have run my app with 512m memory and it worked fine.

The error you mentioned is because your application require more memory than you have mentioned

Could you please share the full stack trace of the error.